# port conflicts for drupal as well as for apache2 on docker in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql, docker, drupal, port

I have installed docker on ubuntu 18.04. In docker, I have created one image of Drupal 8 and other is of mysql. MySQL need apache2 which is at 8080 and Drupal also need port 8080. what should I do to use apache2 and Drupal?

Comment: Use different ports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the apache port from 8080 to 8081 in apache container while starting it as the command given below

```
docker run -dit --name my-running-app -p 8081:80 my-apache2
```

then you can connect from mysql to apache2 using 8081 port.